# Render partials with collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How does the `render :partial => '/comment/form', :collection=>@blog.comments` work? What object does this pass to the partial view? How do I access the comment object in partial view?

Comment: Hi check [this](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/561339136/render-collections) article about partials and rendering collections